# RxJs flatMapLatest/switchMap cancel callback. Where is onCancel()?

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs, observable

I've got 2 nested Observable Streams which do HTTP requests. Now I'd like to display a loading indicator, but can't get it working correctly.

```
var pageStream = Rx.createObservableFunction(_self, 'nextPage')
        .startWith(1)
        .do(function(pageNumber) {
            pendingRequests++;
        })
        .concatMap(function(pageNumber) {
            return MyHTTPService.getPage(pageNumber);
        })
        .do(function(response) {
            pendingRequests--;
        });

Rx.createObservableFunction(_self, 'search')
        .flatMapLatest(function(e) {
            return pageStream;
        })
        .subscribe();



search();
nextPage(2);
nextPage(3);
search();
```

This will trigger `pendingRequests++` 4 times, but `pendingRequests--` only once, because `flatMapLatest` will cancel the inner observable before the first 3 HTTP responses arrive.

I couldn't find anything like an `onCancel` callback. I also tried `onCompleted` and `onError`, but those too won't get triggered by `flatMapLatest`.

Is there any other way to get this working?

Thank you!

### EDIT: Desired loading indicator behavior

1. Example: Single `search()` call.

   - search() -> start loading indicator
   - when search() response comes back -> disable loading indicator
2. Example: `search()` and `nextPage()` call. *(nextPage() is called **before** search() response came back.)*

   - search() -> start loading indicator
   - nextPage() -> indicator is already started, though nothing to do here
   - stop loading indicator after **both** responses arrived
3. Example: `search()`, `search()`. *(search() calls override each other, though the response of the first one can be dismissed)*

   - search() -> start loading indicator
   - search() -> indicator is already started, though nothing to do here
   - stop loading indicator when the response for the **second** search() arrived
4. Example: `search()`, `nextPage()`, `search()`. *(Again: Because of the second search(), the responses from the previous search() and nextPage() can be ignored)*

   - search() -> start loading indicator
   - nextPage() -> indicator is already started, though nothing to do here
   - search() -> indicator is already started, though nothing to do here
   - stop loading indicator when response for the **second** search() arrived
5. Example: `search()`, `nextPage()`. But this time nextPage() is called after search() response came back.

   - search() -> start loading indicator
   - stop loading indicator because search() response arrived
   - nextPage() -> start loading indicator
   - stop loading indicator because nextPage() response arrived

---

I tried using `pendingRequests` counter, because I can have multiple **relevant** requests at the same time (for example: `search(), nextPage(), nextPage()`). Then of course I'd like to disable the loading indicator **after** all those relevant requests finished.

When calling `search(), search()`, the first search() is irrelevant. Same applies for `search(), nextPage(), search()`. In both cases there's only one active relevant request (the last `search()`).

Comment: How should output look like? Should loading indicator be started after calling `search` and stopped after `nextPage`?

Comment: The loading indicator should start when calling either `search` or `nextPage`. And it should be displayed until the last not-canceled response came back. `...` I'll add some examples to the question in a minute (not enough space here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `switchMap` aka `flatMapLatest` you want to trim asap execution of the current inner-stream as new outer-items arrive. It is surely a good design decision as otherwise it would bring a lot of confusion and allow some spooky actions. If you really wanted do do something `onCancel` you can always create your own observable with custom `unsubscribe` callback. But still I would recommend not to couple `unsubscribe` with changing state of the external context. Ideally the `unsubscribe` would only clean up internally used resources.

Nevertheless your particular case can be solved without accessing `onCancel` or similar. The key observation is - if I understood your use case correctly - that on `search` all previous / pending actions may be ignored. So instead of worry about decrementing the counter we can simply start counting from 1.

Some remarks about the snippet:

- used `BehaviorSubject` for counting pending requests - as it is ready to be composed with other streams;
- checked all cases you posted in your question and they work;
- added some fuzzy tests to demonstrate correctness;
- not sure if you wanted to allow `nextPage` when a `search` is still pending - but it seems to be just a matter of using `concatMapTo` vs `merge`;
- used only standard `Rx` operators.

[**PLNKR**](http://plnkr.co/edit/fDj69FSjl4lwhYTtgyq8?p=preview)

```js
console.clear();

const searchSub = new Rx.Subject(); // trigger search 
const nextPageSub = new Rx.Subject(); // triger nextPage
const pendingSub = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(); // counts number of pending requests

const randDurationFactory = min => max => () => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
const randDuration = randDurationFactory(250)(750);
const addToPending = n => () => pendingSub.next(pendingSub.value + n);
const inc = addToPending(1);
const dec = addToPending(-1);

const fakeSearch = (x) => Rx.Observable.of(x)
  .do(() => console.log(`SEARCH-START: ${x}`))
  .flatMap(() => 
    Rx.Observable.timer(randDuration())
    .do(() => console.log(`SEARCH-SUCCESS: ${x}`)))

const fakeNextPage = (x) => Rx.Observable.of(x)
  .do(() => console.log(`NEXT-PAGE-START: ${x}`))
  .flatMap(() =>
    Rx.Observable.timer(randDuration())
    .do(() => console.log(`NEXT-PAGE-SUCCESS: ${x}`)))

// subscribes
searchSub
  .do(() => console.warn('NEW_SEARCH'))
  .do(() => pendingSub.next(1)) // new search -- ingore current state
  .switchMap(
    (x) => fakeSearch(x)
    .do(dec) // search ended
    .concatMapTo(nextPageSub // if you wanted to block nextPage when search still pending
      // .merge(nextPageSub // if you wanted to allow nextPage when search still pending
      .do(inc) // nexpage started
      .flatMap(fakeNextPage) // optionally switchMap
      .do(dec) // nextpage ended
    )
  ).subscribe();

pendingSub
  .filter(x => x !== undefined) // behavior-value initially not defined
  .subscribe(n => console.log('PENDING-REQUESTS', n))

// TEST
const test = () => {
    searchSub.next('s1');
    nextPageSub.next('p1');
    nextPageSub.next('p2');

    setTimeout(() => searchSub.next('s2'), 200)
  }
// test();

// FUZZY-TEST
const COUNTER_MAX = 50;
const randInterval = randDurationFactory(10)(350);
let counter = 0;
const fuzzyTest = () => {
  if (counter % 10 === 0) {
    searchSub.next('s' + counter++)
  }
  nextPageSub.next('p' + counter++);
  if (counter < COUNTER_MAX) setTimeout(fuzzyTest, randInterval());
}

fuzzyTest()
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.11/bundles/Rx.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow. That Looks really promising. Must have a closer look later, to understand what' really going on there.

Comment: @BenjaminM cool, just ping me if you need some clarification.

Answer (score 2):

One way: use the finally operator ([rxjs4 docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/finally.md), [rxjs5 source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/finally.ts)).  Finally triggers whenever the observable is unsubscribed or completes for any reason.

I'd also move the counter logic to inside the concatMap function since you are really counting the getPage requests, *not* the number of values that have gone through.  Its a subtle difference.

```
var pageStream = Rx.createObservableFunction(_self, 'nextPage')
        .startWith(1)
        .concatMap(function(pageNumber) {
            ++pendingRequests;
            // assumes getPage returns an Observable and not a Promise
            return MyHTTPService.getPage(pageNumber)
               .finally(function () { --pendingRequests; })
        });
```

Comment: It still doesn't work as expected. Using your code, it will call `--pendingRequests` twice (which is slightly better than my code, but still not correct). It's getting called for both calls to `search()` but for none of the `nextPage` calls. Btw: `MyHTTPService.getPage` returns an `Observable.fromPromise(...);`, but this shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: I created a JSFiddle that show's the results in browser console: http://jsfiddle.net/8jFJH/1486/

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a solution for your problem from scratch.
For sure it might be written in a more functional way but it works anyway.

This solution is based on `reqStack` which contains all requests (keeping the call order) where a request is an object with `id`, `done` and `type` properties.

When the request is done then `requestEnd` method is called.
There are two conditions and at least one of them is enough to hide a loader.

1. When the last request on the stack was a `search` request then we can hide a loader.
2. Otherwise, all other requests have to be already done.

   ```
   function getInstance() {
    return {
       loaderVisible: false,
       reqStack: [],

       requestStart: function (req){
           console.log('%s%s req start', req.type, req.id)
           if(_.filter(this.reqStack, r => r.done == false).length > 0 && !this.loaderVisible){
               this.loaderVisible = true
               console.log('loader visible')
           }
       },

       requestEnd: function (req, body, delay){
           console.log('%s%s req end (took %sms), body: %s', req.type, req.id, delay, body)
           if(req === this.reqStack[this.reqStack.length-1] && req.type == 'search'){
               this.hideLoader(req)
               return true
           } else if(_.filter(this.reqStack, r => r.done == true).length == this.reqStack.length && this.loaderVisible){
               this.hideLoader(req)
               return true
           } 
           return false
       },

       hideLoader: function(req){
           this.loaderVisible = false
           console.log('loader hidden (after %s%s request)', req.type, req.id)
       },

       getPage: function (req, delay) {
           this.requestStart(req)
           return Rx.Observable
                   .fromPromise(Promise.resolve("<body>" + Math.random() + "</body>"))
                   .delay(delay)
       },

       search: function (id, delay){
           var req = {id: id, done: false, type: 'search'}
           this.reqStack.push(req)
           return this.getPage(req, delay).map(body => {  
                       _.find(this.reqStack, r => r.id == id && r.type == 'search').done = true
                       return this.requestEnd(req, body, delay)
                   })
       },

       nextPage: function (id, delay){
           var req = {id: id, done: false, type: 'nextPage'}
           this.reqStack.push(req)
           return this.getPage(req, delay).map(body => {  
                       _.find(this.reqStack, r => r.id == id && r.type == 'nextPage').done = true
                       return this.requestEnd(req, body, delay)
                   })
       },
   }
   }
   ```

Unit tests in Moca:

```
describe('animation loader test:', function() {

    var sut

    beforeEach(function() {
        sut = getInstance()
    })

    it('search', function (done) {
        sut.search('1', 10).subscribe(expectDidHideLoader)
        testDone(done)
    })

    it('search, nextPage', function (done) {
        sut.search('1', 50).subscribe(expectDidHideLoader)
        sut.nextPage('1', 20).subscribe(expectDidNOTHideLoader)
        testDone(done)
    })

    it('search, nextPage, nextPage', function(done) {
        sut.search('1', 50).subscribe(expectDidHideLoader)
        sut.nextPage('1', 40).subscribe(expectDidNOTHideLoader)
        sut.nextPage('2', 30).subscribe(expectDidNOTHideLoader)
        testDone(done)
    })

    it('search, nextPage, nextPage - reverse', function(done) {
        sut.search('1', 30).subscribe(expectDidNOTHideLoader)
        sut.nextPage('1', 40).subscribe(expectDidNOTHideLoader)
        sut.nextPage('2', 50).subscribe(expectDidHideLoader)
        testDone(done)
    })

    it('search, search', function (done) {
        sut.search('1', 60).subscribe(expectDidNOTHideLoader) //even if it takes more time than search2
        sut.search('2', 50).subscribe(expectDidHideLoader)
        testDone(done)
    })

    it('search, search - reverse', function (done) {
        sut.search('1', 40).subscribe(expectDidNOTHideLoader) 
        sut.search('2', 50).subscribe(expectDidHideLoader)
        testDone(done)
    })

    it('search, nextPage, search', function (done) {
        sut.search('1', 40).subscribe(expectDidNOTHideLoader) //even if it takes more time than search2
        sut.nextPage('1', 30).subscribe(expectDidNOTHideLoader) //even if it takes more time than search2
        sut.search('2', 10).subscribe(expectDidHideLoader)
        testDone(done)
    })

    it('search, nextPage (call after response from search)', function (done) {
        sut.search('1', 10).subscribe(result => {
            expectDidHideLoader(result)
            sut.nextPage('1', 10).subscribe(expectDidHideLoader)
        })
        testDone(done)   
    })

    function expectDidNOTHideLoader(result){
        expect(result).to.be.false
    }

    function expectDidHideLoader(result){
        expect(result).to.be.true
    }

    function testDone(done){
        setTimeout(function(){
            done()
        }, 200)
    }

})
```

Part of the output:

[image]

JSFiddle is [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/mklimus/xjpvbzoa/)

Comment: The result of your tests look good. this Solution should be really interesting for underscore Users :)

Comment: it's `lodash` actaully. I used only `filter` and `find`. You can simply implement them in pure JS but... someone already did it :)

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a much simpler solution, to explain it I'd like to "re-phrase" the examples you gave in your edit:

1. The status is "pending" as long as there are un-closed requests.
2. A response closes all previous requests.

Or, in stream/marbles fashion

(O = request [open], C = response [close], p = pending, x = not pending)

http stream: ------O---O---O---C---O---C---O---O---C---O---

------ Status: x----P--------------x---P----x----P---------x---P---

You can see that the count doesn't matter, we have a flag which is actually on (pending) or off (a response was returned). This true because of you switchMap/flatMap, or as you said at the end of your edit, at each time there's only one active request.

The flag is actually a boolean observable/oberver or simply a subject.

So, what you need is to first define:

```
var hasPending: Subject<boolean> = BehaviorSubject(false);
```

The BehaviorSubject is relevant for 2 reasons:

1. You can set an initial value (false = nothing pending).
2. New subscribers get the last value, hence, even components that are created later will know if you have a pending request.

Than the rest becomes simple, whenever you send out a request, set the pending to 'true', when a request is done, set the pending flag to 'false'.

```
var pageStream = Rx.createObservableFunction(_self, 'nextPage')
    .startWith(1)
    .do(function(pageNumber) {
        hasPending.next(true);
    })
    .concatMap(function(pageNumber) {
        return MyHTTPService.getPage(pageNumber);
    })
    .do(function(response) {
        hasPending.next(false);
    });
```

Rx.createObservableFunction(_self, 'search')
        .flatMapLatest(function(e) {
            return pageStream;
        })
        .subscribe();

This is rxjs 5 syntax, for rxjs 4 use onNext(...)

If you don't need your flat as an observable, just a value, just declare:

```
var hasPending: booolean = false;
```

Then in the .do before the http call do

```
hasPending = true;
```

and in the .do after the http call do

```
hasPending = false;
```

And that's it :-)

Btw, after re-reading everything, you can test this by an even simpler (though somewhat quick and dirty) solution:
Change your post http 'do' call to:

```
.do(function(response) {
        pendingRequests = 0;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. That's a really nice and short solution. But having the number of pending requests would have been really cool for showing some statistics or a progress indicator. Nevertheless it's really simple if one only needs a boolean

Comment: Well, the way you described it, the only statistics you have is that you have a running (active ) query :-) The fact that you had previous calls that were dropped will probably not give the user any data.
If you had a long loading pages, you could do polling to get a specific progress value and display it